# Alamofire: Value of type 'Request' has no member responseImage?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm working on a project, utilizing Alamofire + AlamofireImage. I've just installed AlamofireImage via CocoaPods, and I'm getting this error:

> Value of type 'Request' has no member 'responseImage'

for the line:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, locationURL).responseImage { response in
    if let image = response.result.value { // more code
```

Works fine in all other projects, Podfile install lines are exactly the same as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the entire issue was, because I didn't have to do this in other projects, but importing AlamofireImage fixes the issue. Weirdest thing.